# Epsilon-delta limit definition

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I got $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} \frac{x^2-2x+1}{x-2} = 4$

I need to prove that by delta epsilon. I came to delta ={1/2epsilon,1/2}
Is that right? If not can you explain me how?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\forall \epsilon >0$ and we have to show that ${ \delta  }>0$ such that 
 if $0<\left| x-3 \right| <{ \delta  }$ then $\left| \frac { { x }^{ 2 }-2x+1 }{ x-2 } -4 \right| <\epsilon $

> $$\left| \frac { { x }^{ 2 }-2x+1 }{ x-2 } -4 \right| =\left| \frac { { x }^{ 2 }-2x+1-4x+8 }{ x-2 }  \right| =\left| \frac { { x }^{ 2 }-6x+9 }{ x-2 }  \right| =\left| \frac { { \left( x-3 \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ x-3+1 }  \right|<\\\\ <\left| \frac { { \left( x-3 \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ x-3 }  \right| =\left| x-3 \right| <\delta =\epsilon  $$

Comment: whats happening with -1?

Comment: @Emilia,note that $\left| x-3+1 \right| >\left| x-3 \right| \Rightarrow \quad \frac { 1 }{ \left| x-3+1 \right|  } <\frac { 1 }{ \left| x-3 \right|  } \\ $

Comment: Can you just tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: Where is your work?

Comment: |((x-3)(x-3))/(x-2)| < ε

δ<=1/2

|x-3|<δ<=1/2

-1/2 < x-3 < 1/2
1/2<x/2<3/2
2>1/(x-2)>3/2

δ = min{1/2ε, 1/2}

Comment: please write in LaTex,and it is not a whole answer.

Comment: take a look below

Answer (score 1):

|$\frac {(x-3)(x-3)}{x-2}|$< $\epsilon$

$\delta$ <= $\frac{1}{2}$

|x-3|<$\delta$ <=$\frac{1}{2}$

-$\frac{1}{2}$ < x-3 < $\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{2}$ < x-2 < $\frac{3}{2}$

2>$\frac {1}{x-2}$>$\frac{2}{3}$

$\delta$ = min{$\frac{1}{2}$$\epsilon$, $\frac{1}{2}$}

|$\frac {(x-3)(x-3)}{x-2}|$ < $\delta$*2 = $\epsilon$

Comment: it seems me correct

Comment: ok thank you very much :D I'm glad that I could do it on my own. I hope its really correct :)